# How Can I parse and convert Dates & Times?

Tags: datetime, report, odoo

I met [Odoo](https://www.odoo.com/) for first time a little less than a month ago, and, a DOS Systems Analyst from the 90's, am helping to implement it for a small but fast growing local manufacturer.  Largely out of the industry the last 15 years, I'm not pro, but fast learning Python, HTML (some past exper) and Java...

I've been through the [Developer Docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/index.html), as well as the Developer's Cookbook & Essentials, and a variety of online tutorials (just about everything Google could come up with from several search word combinations).

I read the closed post asking about this and get that there's apparently no actual Odoo reference...

Can someone please tell me where I might find 'date/time' parse and conversion functions that I can access from a report that is using the 'canned' 'hr.employee' model?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t t-name="hr_attendance.report_attendancelog">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-call="report.external_layout">
            <div class="page">
                <div class="oe_structure"/>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <h2><br/>Attendance Log: </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <table class="table table-condensed mt32">
                    <thead>
                        <th><strong>Date / Time</strong></th>
                        <th><strong> Operation</strong></th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                            <t t-set="DspDate" t-value="o.name"/>
                            <t t-set="DspTime" t-value="o.name"/>

<!-- I want to parse 'o.name', which is 'date time' format (from
             Attendance record) to separate 'Date' and 'Time' fields... -->
                        <!-- t t-set="DspDate" t-value="FUNC?(o.name)"/ -->
                        <!-- t t-set="DspTime" t-value="FUNC?(o.name)"/ -->
<!-- and do calcs with date & time...) -->
                        <!-- t t-set="ClcDt1" t-value="FUNC?('PrvDt')"/ -->
                        <!-- t t-set="ClcDt2" t-value="FUNC?(DspDate)"/ -->
                        <!-- t t-set="ClcTm1" t-value="FUNC?('PrvTm')"/ -->
                        <!-- t t-set="ClcTm2" t-value="FUNC?(DspTime)"/ -->

                            <tr>
                                <t t-if="ClcDt1 == ClcDt2">
                                    <td><span t-esc="DspDate"/></td>
                                    <td><span t-esc="DspTime"/></td>
                                    <td><span t-esc="o.action"/></td>
                                </t
                            </tr>
                        </t>
                        <tr class="border-black">
                            <td colspan="3"><strong>Total period</strong></td>
                            <td><strong t-esc="o.worked_hours"/></td -->
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</t>
```

I prefixed 'br/' to H2 to keep the it properly positioned (only shows on the first page), but subsequent pages obscure the col headers behind the layout header... this is probably obvious and I'm oblivious, but how can I adjust the 'H2' position to be below the 'header' setup by 'report.external_layout'??

Comment: This is first page: [link](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AkHbZineHVjYgqR0W2mt2AAUgwxrIw)  This is second: [link](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AkHbZineHVjYgqR14KFH7orGUuVVIw)   I moved the H2 output is apparently behind the ext layout header.  Note on Page two, the upward shift of the col headers... the rest of the pages print in like manner.

Comment: This moves the Header up and down (affects the 'external_layout' formatting), but doesn't solve the issue, as, the rest of the page is moving up and down commensurately...  I believe from what I've read, that there is a way to actually set the starting position for 'rendering' (usage?), which, I'm hoping, should affect the H2 positioning, shifting it's 'relative to the header' position or absolute position down...  The issue includes the body, as, on pages 2+, without H2, it is shifted; hence the disappearance of the col hdrs, which display fine on page 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On QWeb rendering you can use the python libs time, datetime and relativedelta. They are included in the so called QWeb context which is used for the evaluation (python eval) of the code in reports. You can see this in Odoo code [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py#L1055).

That means you do something like this:

```xml
<t t-set="DspDate" t-value="datetime.datetime.strptime(o.name, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')" />
```

I prefer parser classes for reports to define some common functions. For example: you can define the function `getDate` doing your parsing or transforming stuff. The report code will be much better with parser functions:

```xml
<t t-set="DspDate" t-value="getDate(o.name)" />
```

Comment: Thanks CZ!  I get what you're saying and totally agree that calling a Python coded function is a far superior solution to trying to 'process' within the report view... I get that much about OO development (particularly with Odoo, which seems to be all about views...)...  The challenge would lie in my novice experience with such...  I know how to create, load and use the necessary function(s), I just don't know where to create them that the report will be able to access, that won't be 'blown away' by system updates...  We will be doing a module, but atm just trying to get a usable report...

Comment: So, using datetime.datetime.strptime(o.name, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d/%m/%Y') as shown above, I get an error about ['unconverted data'](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AkHbZineHVjYgqR7PfxDJCqT-F3lpA)... and it's indicating the time that I'm trying to strip...  do I maybe need to somehow specify a 'bucket' for the time?

Comment: Oh i missed that, you have to use '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' as datetime format for `strptime()`. I will edit my answer.